# How to add fields from different model in JSON response in express?

Tags: express

I am working on this express app and I want to know if there is any way to add fields from different schema in the JSON response?
Here is the code. 

This is the first schema

```
const restaurantSchema = mongoose.Schema({
title: { type: String, required: true},
prepration_time: {type: String,required:true},
timings: {type: String,required:true},
listed: {type: Boolean},
});
```

This is the second schema

```
    const menuSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    dish: {type: String,required:true},
    category: {type: String,required:true},
    price: {type: String,required:true},
    restaurant: { type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,ref: 'Restaurant' , require: true }

});
```

I have used the Schema type to set the relation and I want to display the menu schema as a field in the restaurant schema.

Here is the router function:

```
    router.get('',(req,res,next)=>{
    Restaurant.find()
    .then(result =>{
        console.log(result);
        res.status(200).json({
            message: "Fetched",
            restaurants: result
        });
    });    
});
```

Comment: Just add a `menu` property to your `result` before you pass them into the `.json({...})`.

Answer (score 0):

```
const restaurantSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  title: { type: String, required: true},
  prepration_time: {type: String,required:true},
  timings: {type: String,required:true},
  listed: {type: Boolean},
  menu : {type: Schema.types.ObjectId, ref:'menus'}
});
```

Make sure **ref** should be your collection name. While adding data to `restaurant` collection make sure to add id of a menu document in `menu field` in `restaurant collection`
ex :

```
{
  title: 'Restaurant name',
  prepration_time: '45 min',
  timings: '12:24pm',
  listed: true,
  menu : '123sfererdfd23422' // _id from menu collection
}
```

Then Query Like This

```
Restaurant.find()
.populate('menu')
.then(result =>{
    console.log(result);
    res.status(200).json({
        message: "Fetched",
        restaurants: result
    });
});
```